# ¿Cómo filtrar NULL de un SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sé que el pivot no es disponible en MySQL. Entonces como seria possible hacer pivotar la columna de `Occupation` en `OCCUPATIONS` de manera que cada `Name` se ordene alfabéticamente y se muestre debajo de su correspondiente Ocupación. Los encabezados de las columnas de salida deben ser Doctor, Professor, Singer y Actor, respectivamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté:

```
SELECT 
    (o.Name CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Doctor') As Doctor,
    (o.Name CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Professor') As Professor,
    (o.Name CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Singer') As Singer,
    (o.Name CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Actor') As Actor
FROM OCCUPATIONS o GROUP BY o.Occupation;
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Doctor') As Doctor,
    (o.Name CASE WHEN o.Occupation' at line 2
```

Me gustaria obtener:

```
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

## Actualizacion

Intenté con

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN o.Name ELSE NULL END) as Doctor,
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Professor' THEN o.Name ELSE NULL END) as Professor,
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Singer' THEN o.Name ELSE NULL END) as Singer,
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Actor' THEN o.Name ELSE NULL END) as Actor
FROM OCCUPATIONS o;
```

Y me devuelve:

```
NULL Ashley NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL Samantha
Julia NULL NULL NULL
NULL Britney NULL NULL
NULL Maria NULL NULL
NULL Meera NULL NULL
Priya NULL NULL NULL
NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL Jennifer
NULL NULL NULL Ketty
NULL Belvet NULL NULL
NULL Naomi NULL NULL
NULL NULL Jane NULL
NULL NULL Jenny NULL
NULL NULL Kristeen NULL
NULL NULL Christeen NULL
NULL NULL NULL Eve
Aamina NULL NULL NULL
```

Pero como hacer para solo haber NULL al final de las columnas en lugar de los medios?

Intenté remplazar los ELSE NULL con:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN o.Name ELSE '' END) as Doctor,
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Professor' THEN o.Name ELSE '' END) as Professor,
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Singer' THEN o.Name ELSE '' END) as Singer,
    (CASE WHEN o.Occupation = 'Actor' THEN o.Name ELSE '' END) as Actor
FROM OCCUPATIONS o;
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
Ashley 
Samantha
Julia 
Britney 
Maria 
Meera 
Priya 
Priyanka 
Jennifer
Ketty
Belvet 
Naomi 
Jane 
Jenny 
Kristeen 
Christeen 
Eve
Aamina
```

Comment: Esta mal escrito el `CASE WHEN`, deberia ser `CASE case_value WHEN`, como dice la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: y de esa manera a cada uno de tus `CASE`

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM  Sin embargo, me gustaría tener columnas con los nombres de las personas correspondientes a sus ocupaciones. He puesto un ejemplo del output deseada

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica entonces simplemente cambia `THEN o.Occupation` por `THEN o.name` y quita el `GROUP BY o.Occupation`

Comment: Muchas gracias @JuanRivera ¿Sabe usted cómo limpiar los NULL y ponerlos sólo al final de cada columna y sólo si son necesarios para hacer una tabla bonita?

Comment: `else '' end` en lugar de `else null end`

Comment: ¿Qué versión de mysql usas?

Comment: @jachguate Version 8.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para MySQL version < 8.0, puedes usar variables de usuario para asignar el número de renglón por ocupación, y usarlo como agrupador:

```
SELECT min(if(Occupation='Doctor'   ,Name,null)) Doctor
     , min(if(Occupation='Professor',Name,null)) Professor
     , min(if(Occupation='Singer'   ,Name,null)) Singer
     , min(if(Occupation='Actor'    ,Name,null)) Actor
  FROM ( SELECT @n1:=0, @n2:=0, @n3:=0, @n4:=0 ) v   
    JOIN ( SELECT CASE Occupation
                    WHEN 'Doctor'    THEN @n1:=@n1+1
                    WHEN 'Professor' THEN @n2:=@n2+1
                    WHEN 'Singer'    THEN @n3:=@n3+1
                    WHEN 'Actor'     THEN @n4:=@n4+1
                  END n
                , occ.*
             FROM ( SELECT *
                      FROM occupations
                      ORDER BY Occupation, Name
                  ) occ
         ) t
  GROUP BY n
```

La idea es que a partir de `occ`:

| Name | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Actor |
| Julia | Actor |
| Maria | Actor |
| Jenny | Doctor |
| Samantha | Doctor |
| Ashley | Professor |
| Christeen | Professor |
| Ketty | Professor |
| Meera | Singer |
| Priya | Singer |

Calcular el número de renglón con las variables de usuario, una por cada ocupación `t`:

| n | Name | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | Actor |
| 2 | Julia | Actor |
| 3 | Maria | Actor |
| 1 | Jenny | Doctor |
| 2 | Samantha | Doctor |
| 1 | Ashley | Professor |
| 2 | Christeen | Professor |
| 3 | Ketty | Professor |
| 1 | Meera | Singer |
| 2 | Priya | Singer |

Que al agrupar por número de renglón:

| n | Name | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane Jenny Ashley Meera | Actor Doctor Professor Singer |
| 2 | Julia Samantha Christeen Priya | Actor Doctor Professor Singer |
| 3 | Maria Ketty | Actor Professor |

Sólo resta hacer la *agregación condicional* por ocupación

```
min(if(Occupation=<OCUPACION>,Name,null))
```

sabiendo que por cada `n` hay a lo mucho un valor por ocupación, por lo que la función de agregación puede ser cualquiera aplicable a una cadena: `min(), max(), group_concat()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esto es exactamente lo que fue buscando. Sin embargo, podrias explicar un poquito como funciona? No entiendo bien la primera parte `min(if`... Y no soy seguro que la secunda da el index los nombres tampoco

Comment: @Revolucion, como funciona, paso a paso, lo expliqué yo en [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/447112/21). Esta hace lo mismo, con una sintaxis diferente y de una vez resumidos los pasos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte de ir transformando los datos en CTE's para lograr tu objetivo.

1. Numerar cada registro por ocupación
2. Crear la distribución en columnas, con un dato por cada fila
3. Resumir los datos basándonos en el número que le hemos asignado a cada registro.

Paso por paso, sería algo como:

```
with
Paso1 as (
select   row_number() over (partition by ocupation order by name) as numero
       , ocupation
       , name
  from ocupations
)
,
Paso2 as (
select   numero
       , case ocupation when 'Doctor' then name end Doctor
       , case ocupation when 'Professor' then name end Professor
       , case ocupation when 'Singer' then name end Singer
       , case ocupation when 'Actor' then name end Actor
  from Paso1
)
,
Paso3 as (
select numero
       , coalesce(max(Doctor), '') Doctor
       , coalesce(max(Professor), '') Professor
       , coalesce(max(Singer), '') Singer
       , coalesce(max(Actor), '') Actor
  from Paso2 
 group by numero
)
select Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor
  from Paso3
```

La consulta, al final, se puede hacer mucho más corta, pero eso ya queda de ejercicio para ti. Si has comprendido cada paso, no dudo que puedas transformarla con facilidad.